# How to install traceroute utility?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm getting this:

```
atul@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install traceroute
[sudo] password for atul: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package traceroute is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'traceroute' has no installation candidate
```

Can any one tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: i m running 12.10

Comment: You really need to upgrade to a supported release. Also, how have you been upgrading the machine? Through the terminal or the update manager? If the terminal, what commands have you been using? You have a lot of packages not upgraded.

Comment: i m using ubuntu virtually so basically i do not update it but now i m updating it using update manager

Answer (score 22):

it has to be installed with the package `inetutils-traceroute`.

```
sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute
```

Comment: thx,but now i get this

Comment: atul@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute
[sudo] password for atul: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Enter `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock` and then try.

Comment: root@ubuntu:/home/atul# rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
root@ubuntu:/home/atul# apt-get install inetutils-traceroute
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  inetutils-traceroute
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 493 not upgraded.
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/

Comment: root@ubuntu:/home/atul# traceroute
The program 'traceroute' can be found in the following packages:
 * inetutils-traceroute
 * traceroute
Try: apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: Enter `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`. then again try. meny files in your system are locked for some reasons. you need to `sudo rm <LOCKED FILE>` to remove the lock.

Comment: thx for u r help it's working......