# Unable to download packages

Tags: apt, sudo, source-packages

Needing to download 'traceroute' for some work that I have to do, I tried to download the package using 'sudo apt-get install'. After looking online, I saw that I might have to update the software but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install traceroute
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package traceroute is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'traceroute' has no installation candidate

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install update
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package update
```

P.S. inetutils-traceroute is not working, therefore I need another answer to be able to download the package.

Comment: The answer below and in the linked duplicate is correct, though `inetutils-traceroute` is in the universe repositories, do you have them enabled?

Comment: Don't think so, how would I go about enabling universe repositories

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/148645/320386 or the answer below it if you want to use command line.

Comment: Still nothing, I've activated the universe repository, but it still says that:    E: Package 'traceroute' has no installation candidate

Comment: FYI the `tracepath` utility has much of the same functionality, and should be installed by default iirc

Comment: That error message makes it look like your not using the `sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute` command

Comment: When I use 'sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute', I get :   E: Unable to locate package inetutils

Answer (score 8, accepted):

firstly run the command below to update repositories if prompted to press y/n press y:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

afterwards run this command to update existing software, if prompted to press y/n press y:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then install traceroute with the command below, once again, if prompted to press y/n, press y:

```
sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding this post ([How to install traceroute utility?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491868/how-to-install-traceroute-utility/491878))

use `sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute`

best regards,

Comment: Thanks, but still nothing, still says unable to locate package.

Comment: can you paste what it says ?

Comment: Sorry, wrote the wrong thing, it says: 
    E: Unable to locate package inetutils-traceroute

Comment: what does it says ?

Comment: Sorry, wrote the wrong thing, it says: 
    E: Unable to locate package inetutils-traceroute

Comment: (apt:inetutils-traceroute) add this ppa [copy paste it in your firefox browser url], then `sudo apt-get update` then 'sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute'

Comment: I've already tried to update, nothing's worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45369/discussion-between-ahmed-al-attar-and-campers).

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers on different questions. It just creates more work for the moderators. If the questions are so similar that the same answer works on each, then the later of the two is likely a duplicate and should be flagged as such.